# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value, when the value ISN'T nil

Tags: swift

I am experiencing an issue where Swift is crashing while accessing a variable of mine, yLabelMax. It crashes with the following information:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I added a bit of checking to see what was going on with the following code:

```
if (yValueMax != nil){
    print ("value is \(yValueMax)")
}
else{
    print (" is nil")
}
```

When I run this code, the console prints:

```
value is 954.0
is nil
```

So it appears that the code is running both the if and the else statement. How can the variable both be nil and contain a value at the same time?

Comment: yValueMax is a `String` ?

Comment: Is it perhaps running twice?

Answer (score 2):

OK, goodness, I feel dumb, but thank you to jtbandes for guiding me in the right direction. I had the code inadvertently running twice.